# $scope.$watch not working

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, watch

Hello i have the following service:

```
angular.module('vendor').service('ticketService', function() {

    var ticketList = [];
    var result = false;

    var addToCart = function(type, ticket, tSI) {
        var data = {}

        if (type =='event')
        {
            data = {
                type: type,
                tSI:  tSI
            }
        }

        if (type =='bus')
        {
            data = {
                type: type,
                company: ticket.company,
                date: ticket.when,
                number: ticket.number || 1,
                tSI:  tSI
            }
        }

        if (type == 'extra')
        {
            data = {
                type: type,
                extra: ticket,
                tSI:  tSI
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '/cart',
            headers: {
                'X-XSRF-Token': $("meta[name='csrf_token']").attr("content")
            },
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                ticket.hasTicket = true;
                result = 200;
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        addToCart: addToCart,
        result: result
    };

});
```

Now i call this service in my controller:

```
angular.module('vendor').controller('TicketController', ['$http', '$scope', '$rootScope', 'ticketService', '$timeout', function($http, $scope, $rootScope, ticketService, $timeout) {
    $scope.addToCart = function(type, ticket, tSI, $index) {
                $scope.selectedIndex = $index;

                $scope.isWorking = true;
                $scope.isReady = false;

                ticketService.addToCart(type, ticket, tSI);
                $rootScope.$broadcast('TICKET_ADDED', true);

            };

            $scope.$watch('ticketService.result', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                alert(ticketService.result);
                if (typeof newVal !== 'undefined') {
                    if (ticketService.result == 200) {
                        $scope.isWorking = false;
                        $scope.isComplete = true;
                    }
                }
            });
}]);
```

When a ticket is added i want to be able to return a result back to the controller in this case 200, i am currently trying to watch the value of ticketService.result but when the function completes $watch does not do anything.

Comment: Are you getting any error in console. Plz check it once

Answer (score 0):

Better assign `ticketService.result` to the `$scope` property and listen to that property.

Use, `$scope.result = ticketService.result`.

```
$scope.$watch('result', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                alert(ticketService.result);
                if (typeof newVal !== 'undefined') {
                    if (ticketService.result == 200) {
                        $scope.isWorking = false;
                        $scope.isComplete = true;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Another option would be,

Instead of creating a `$watch`, `emit` the event from the service and `listen` to it in your scope.

Like below:

Inject `$rootScope` in your service.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '/cart',
            headers: {
                'X-XSRF-Token': $("meta[name='csrf_token']").attr("content")
            },
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                ticket.hasTicket = true;
                result = 200;
                $rootScope.$emit("result-changed");
            }
        });
```

in your controller,

```
$scope.$on("result-changed", function(event, data) {
    if (ticketService.result == 200) {
          $scope.isWorking = false;
          $scope.isComplete = true;
    }
});
```

This will reduce the number of `$watch` you may be having in your application. Only when the event fires, the listener in your controller will fire.

Comment: Instead of primitive `result` can you bind it to an object? Like `ticketservice = {}`. `ticketservice.result = false`

Comment: The watch works when the page loads initially but when the value changes nothing occurs, if i do ticketService = {} it still doesn't make any difference. I can understand why.

Comment: From what i'm seeing the value of result never gets changed in the ajax success function, result is always false even though i assigned 200 to it. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try to watch a function which returns the `tickectService.result` value instead of a string:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return ticketService.result; }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
            alert(ticketService.result);
            if (typeof newVal !== 'undefined') {
                if (ticketService.result == 200) {
                    $scope.isWorking = false;
                    $scope.isComplete = true;
                }
            }
        });
```